# Need an idea about how to open a popup which contain only post created form in wordpress admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I need an idea about how to open a popup which contain only post created form in wordpress admin.

What I am doing is, I created a custom post type and in that I added dropdown of normal posts.
admin can select post from it during creating custom post type.
At this stage it is fine.

But if there is no post then I am displaying a link "Create New Post" with link to "/wp-admin/post-new.php". so when admin click on it, he redirect to that page.

BUT my idea is I want to open a popup of create post same as post-new.php page and admin can create post at same time (without redirect).

Is their any form API in wordpress because I want to show all metaboxes that other plugins added to post-new.php.

Comment: I want to use same form for any content type, thats why i need an idea with form API...

Comment: Well, you will need write code for a popup window. Using some jquery plugin such as fancybox. And in that window you will could load the post-new.php page via ajax. Most people here are willing to help as long as you show that you have done some work, have tried to write some code.

Comment: thanks gdaniel. I am working on it. And If I will get any success then I will post my code here..